# Couchdb removal

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I am trying to remove couchdb in my Ubuntu Server ( 10.04 ) and I received the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing couchdb (--purge):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do i fix this?

I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove couchdb
sudo apt-get purge couchdb
sudo aptitude remove couchdb
```

but to no avail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be more worried about how you managed to get your installation so badly wedged in the first place, myself.

Have you tried following the recommendation that `dpkg` gave you, and reinstalling the package to get everything into a consistent state before you try your purge again?

Comment: hello, yes I have tried the recommendation dpkg gave me. But when I try to install i receive the error message which says: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of couchdb:
 couchdb depends on couchdb-bin (= 0.10.0-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of couchdb-bin on system is 1.0.1-0ubuntu3~lucid1.
dpkg: error processing couchdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchdb`

Comment: Your repositories list is hosed; if you want packages from Lucid, then **run lucid**; don't try installing individual packages piecemeal, you'll make a mess of it.  Upgrade your entire system and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it with

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq couchdb
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove --force couchdb
```

Comment: Don't recommend using `--force-*` options; it only makes things worse.